# Taking files as input in command line arguments in python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, openpyxl

I am taking path as the input in command line , but it is not taking input from the other directory, my code is this

```
filename1 = os.path.basename(sys.argv[1])
filename2 = os.path.basename(sys.argv[2])
filename3 = os.path.basename(sys.argv[3])
wk1 = openpyxl.load_workbook (filename1)
wk2 = openpyxl.load_workbook (filename2)
```

and passing command line arguments like this,

```
python Final.py "C://Users//Folder One//Folder Two//Input1.xlsx" 
"C://Users//Folder One//Folder Three//Input2.xlsx" "C://Users//Folder 
One//Folder Four/Output.xlsx"
```

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Input1.xlsx'`

I need to take input 2 files and store the output in third file i.e `Output.xlsx`. 3rd argument decides the path for the output file.

Comment: If you only take the filename (not the full path) then how would that work without first setting the working/current directory before calling `load_workbook` ?  You pass the full path, so why only use the filename?

Comment: @Tim Williams I am getting error in command line arguments i.e File Not found   for output file it is working fine but for the input file it is not working

Comment: You are using double quotes twice for the 2nd argument. Why is it so?

Comment: It is just writing mistake here @shahkalpesh

Comment: Please include the error message.

Comment: Added @CharlieClark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're trying to read from another directory then maybe you should pass the filepath directly to the load_workbook function instead.

The os.path.basename function returns the name of the file *Input1.xlsx*. Since you invoked the script from a different location, it will fail to detect the file from the source directory. Right now your script attempts to to look for your input files from the same directory as your Final.py, or wherever else that you've navigated to prior to attempting to load the workbooks.

Comment: I tried this, `wk1 = openpyxl.load_workbook (argv[1])` this is not working @kerwei

Comment: argv[1] or sys.argv[1]?